# Unable to remove stackTrace in response from Restcontroller. Just wanted the respose body instead getting unnecessary stackTrace

Tags: spring-boot

```
{
  "cause": null,
  "stackTrace": [
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "saveOrder",
      "fileName": "OrderServiceImp.java",
      "lineNumber": 21,
      "className": "com.nextnepal.justnep.service.orderService.OrderServiceImp",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "placeOrder",
      "fileName": "OrderController.java",
      "lineNumber": 23,
      "className": "com.nextnepal.justnep.controller.order.OrderController",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "invoke0",
      "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
      "lineNumber": -2,
      "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
      "nativeMethod": true
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
      "lineNumber": 62,
      "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
      "lineNumber": 43,
      "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "Method.java",
      "lineNumber": 566,
      "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doInvoke",
      "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
      "lineNumber": 190,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invokeForRequest",
      "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
      "lineNumber": 138,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invokeAndHandle",
      "fileName": "ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java",
      "lineNumber": 106,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invokeHandlerMethod",
      "fileName": "RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java",
      "lineNumber": 888,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "handleInternal",
      "fileName": "RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java",
      "lineNumber": 793,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "handle",
      "fileName": "AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java",
      "lineNumber": 87,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doDispatch",
      "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 1040,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doService",
      "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 943,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "processRequest",
      "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 1006,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doPost",
      "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 909,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "service",
      "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 660,
      "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "service",
      "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 883,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "service",
      "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
      "lineNumber": 741,
      "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 231,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 166,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "WsFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 53,
      "className": "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 193,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 166,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
      "fileName": "RequestContextFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 100,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 119,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 193,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 166,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
      "fileName": "FormContentFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 93,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 119,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 193,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 166,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
      "fileName": "CharacterEncodingFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 201,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
      "lineNumber": 119,
      "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 193,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doFilter",
      "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
      "lineNumber": 166,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "StandardWrapperValve.java",
      "lineNumber": 202,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "StandardContextValve.java",
      "lineNumber": 96,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "AuthenticatorBase.java",
      "lineNumber": 526,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "StandardHostValve.java",
      "lineNumber": 139,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "ErrorReportValve.java",
      "lineNumber": 92,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "fileName": "StandardEngineValve.java",
      "lineNumber": 74,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "service",
      "fileName": "CoyoteAdapter.java",
      "lineNumber": 343,
      "className": "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "service",
      "fileName": "Http11Processor.java",
      "lineNumber": 408,
      "className": "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "process",
      "fileName": "AbstractProcessorLight.java",
      "lineNumber": 66,
      "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "process",
      "fileName": "AbstractProtocol.java",
      "lineNumber": 861,
      "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "doRun",
      "fileName": "NioEndpoint.java",
      "lineNumber": 1579,
      "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": "SocketProcessorBase.java",
      "lineNumber": 49,
      "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "runWorker",
      "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
      "lineNumber": 1128,
      "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
      "lineNumber": 628,
      "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": "app",
      "moduleName": null,
      "moduleVersion": null,
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": "TaskThread.java",
      "lineNumber": 61,
      "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable",
      "nativeMethod": false
    },
    {
      "classLoaderName": null,
      "moduleName": "java.base",
      "moduleVersion": "11.0.4",
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": "Thread.java",
      "lineNumber": 834,
      "className": "java.lang.Thread",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }
  ],
  "code": 200,
  "message": "order successfully submitted",
  "suppressed": [],
  "localizedMessage": "order successfully submitted"
}
```

Comment: can you please share your controller code please

Comment: please add the custom exception in question and the Message class belongs to ?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on here, but taking a stab in the dark, I'd try adding

```
server:
  error:
    include-stacktrace: on-trace-param
```

to your application.properties.

See API [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.IncludeStacktrace.html#ON_TRACE_PARAM).

Answer (score 0):

I uses server.error.include-stacktrace=never

Comment: sir (server.error.include-stacktrace=neve) doesn't work .can You provide another solution please??

Comment: please share the controller and custom exception class, dependencies pom or gradle and spring boot version into question